# str1 != "NO" returns true while str1 is "NO"

Tags: java, string-comparison

I have this code:

```
url = new URL("http://anurl");
urlConn = url.openConnection();
dis = new DataInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream()); 
num = dis.readLine();
System.out.println(num); //prints "NO"
if(num != "NO") {
   //this code is executed
}
```

I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't use != or == when comparing strings. It will do a comparison of the object reference (you can think of it as the pointer to the object) and return true/false depending on if it is the exact same instance of the string or not. Use String.equals() to do it right.

Comment: Yup. If `string1 == string2` works in Java, it is usually by coincidence.

Comment: I think "object comparison" is a somewhat ambiguous description, although the rest of your answer makes it somewhat clearer. "Reference comparison" is clearer IMO.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You're right. I just assumed that reference comparison would be "harder word" to get. Will edit,

Comment: Thanks. +1 now :) I see what you mean about it being perhaps more complex - but it's the kind of thing where without understanding the concept of references, the whole question becomes impossible anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

`!=` compares *references*, not *objects*.  You need to use `if (!num.equals("NO"))`.

Answer (score 2):

`==` tests whether values refer to the same object. Use `"NO".equals(num)`.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to compare String then use equals

```
if(!"NO".equals(num)) {
   //this code is executed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try it with:

```
if(num.equals"NO") {
   //this code is executed
}
```

Please read [this](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

== and != will do an exact bit wise comparison of the reference variables. In other words they will do a comparison of the addresses referred by the references and not the values. Since they are pointing to different objects so different addresses [which are stored in the references] are compared. That is why you have that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

String comparison in Java requries *equals*:

```
if (!num.equals("NO")) {
  ...
}
```

Your code might work in C# or in some other programming language, but not in Java.